# how to properly display a value from the stack using a system call

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, system-calls

```
compiler: nasm
asm: x64
OS: Debian x64
```

Hello, I'm starting to get deeper and deeper into the assembly, and in this case I want to train a bit with a pile.

I wanted to push the value "AAAAAA" onto the stack and just display it with the sys_write system call, but after compiling the code nothing displays.

```
.text:
        global _start

_start:

        mov rax,'AAAAAAA'
        push rax

        mov rax,0x1
        mov rdx, 9
        mov rsi, [rsp+4*rsi]
        mov rdi,1
        syscall

        ;exit
        mov rax, 60
        mov rdi, 0
        syscall
```

before, I tried yet with this version

```
        mov rax,0x1
        mov rdx, 9
        pop rsi
        mov rdi,1
        syscall
```

but still not working, I miss some important detail in my knowledge, I feel that I'm getting closer but I can't get it out :(

Could this thread be a potential cause of my problem? :):
[Why do system calls use a different stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65869471/why-do-system-calls-use-a-different-stack)

Comment: `write(int fd, void *buf, size_t len)` wants a *pointer* in RSI.  You're loading the *value*.  (Or loading some garbage, since you don't set RSI before using it in an addressing mode; in a dynamically-linked executable RSI would likely be non-zero on entry to _start!).  So for example, `mov rsi, rsp`.  See also [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) for an example of printing from a stack buffer.

Comment: [Printing something in stack (assembly)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46750560) shows a nice simple example, but the question has a different problem from yours.

Comment: @PeterCordes it's funny, it was enough to change ```mov``` to ```lea rsi, [rsp]```, but I was sure that "mov" was already working on addresses in memory

Comment: `mov reg, [address]` loads from memory.  `lea reg, [address]` puts the address into the destination, just doing the address math.  If the address you want is already in a register, `lea reg, [reg]` is just an inefficient way to write `mov reg,reg`. Note the lack of brackes on the source operand in that mov: it's *not* using the register as an address, just taking the bits from it.